# JOOQ : Creating subqueries using WITH clause (using plain SQL)

Tags: java, sql, jooq, with-statement

I am having trouble generating subquery using "WITH" clause with "plain SQL Query". Use case is that I have an SQL and I just want to use it as a with subquery and create a query on top of that.

Example:

Query I have:

```java
"SELECT a,b,c FROM T"
```

I want to create:

```sql
WITH "t1" as ( SELECT a,b,c FROM T ) 
SELECT a,b FROM "t1";
```

I am trying to use DSL.with(...) but it only takes SelectStep or CTE. I also noticed that we can't create CTE using plain SQL. Please help with this if there is any way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from jOOQ 3.15, the [`WithAsStep.as()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/WithAsStep.html) methods take a [`ResultQuery`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html) as an argument, not just a `Select`. This means you can wrap a [`DSL.resultQuery(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#resultQuery(java.lang.String)) (i.e. a ["plain SQL template"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)). Just write:

```java
ctx.with(name("t1"))
   .as(resultQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM t"))
   .select(field(unquotedName("a")), field(unquotedName("b")))
   .from(name("t1"))
   .fetch();
```

Assuming, as always, this static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas, I see that it is added recently, what would be the other ways to achieve this in older releases (if any) ?

Comment: @tolani: What prevents you from upgrading?

Comment: Nothing, upgraded @Lukas